# React: How to optimize for creation and destruction of 200 elements with one click?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a grid of squares, where each square represents a transaction.

This grid can grow to 200 squares. Therefore, I have added pagination with a limit of 2 pages. Each page has a maximum of 100 squares.

Here's the code for that grid:

```
const BlockCard = ({ blockNumber, timestamp, transactions }) => {
  ...
  const [isViewingFirstPage, setIsViewingFirstPage] = useState(true);

  ...

  const paginatedTransactions = isViewingFirstPage
    ? transactions.slice(0, 100)
    : transactions.slice(100, 200);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CardWrapper>
        ...
        <CardGrid>
          {paginatedTransactions.map(({ hash, from, to, value }) => (
            <TransactionSquare
              key={hash}
              hash={hash}
              from={from}
              to={to}
              value={value}
              ethToUsdPrice={ethToUsdPrice}
            />
          ))}
        </CardGrid>
        <MoreTransactionsButton
          hide={transactions.length <= 100}
          onClick={() => setIsViewingFirstPage(!isViewingFirstPage)}>
          {isViewingFirstPage ? (
            <React.Fragment>
              <ButtonText>{transactions.length - 100} more TX</ButtonText>
              <CaretWrapper>
                <Caret src={ICON_CARET_RIGHT} />
              </CaretWrapper>
            </React.Fragment>
          ) : (
            <ButtonText>Back</ButtonText>
          )}
        </MoreTransactionsButton>
        ...
      </CardWrapper>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

You can see the whole file / app here: https://github.com/EdmundMai/ethereum-explorer/blob/master/src/components/homepage/BlockCard.js#L80

I noticed that when clicking the `MoreTransactionsButton` to load the second page of transactions, a considerable amount of time is needed to reconcile. The browser needs to 1) Destroy 100 squares and then 2) Create up to 100 more squares.

I admittedly do not have much experience debugging performance in React. I am using React 16+ and it seems like I have only the Chrome Performance tab to work with.

[image: How]

Would there be a more efficient way of writing this?

Here's a link to my repo, no special install instructions just `npm install; npm start` if you want to pull it and run it locally: https://github.com/EdmundMai/ethereum-explorer

Comment: Hi! The problem is that you are rendering a tooltip for *each square*. You should render a single tooltip with dynamic content instead.

Comment: Hi! But I need the tooltip to appear next to the individual square

Comment: In the parent component create a single tooltip component that receives either a reference to the object that needs to be attached to or a position object with the coordinates and the content that should render.